# How do I make the mini-buffer window larger? It is not big enough to display up/down arrows by default

Tags: emacs

> How do I make the mini-buffer window larger? It is not big enough to display up/down arrows by default.

As can be seen below, the mini-buffer window is not sufficiently large to display the down-array and this bothers me.

Is there a way to increase its height so that its appearance adapt to its content?

It should be said, that I've installed the leuven theme and zoom-frm.el additions.

[image]

Comment: I can't find a way to set a minimum size for the minibuffer (you can set the maximum size with `max-mini-window-height`).  This is actually a problem with your GUI theme.  I use the Lucid GUI (because it doesn't have this bug: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2281/651), which doesn't even have arrows.  Try using a different GUI or try changing your theme/settings.

Answer (score 3):

`C-h v resize-mini-windows`:

```
resize-mini-windows is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is grow-only

Documentation:
How to resize mini-windows (the minibuffer and the echo area).
A value of nil means don't automatically resize mini-windows.
A value of t means resize them to fit the text displayed in them.
A value of `grow-only', the default, means let mini-windows grow only;
they return to their normal size when the minibuffer is closed, or the
echo area becomes empty.
```

To let minibuffer windows resize automatically, set this variable to either `t` or `grow-only`, in your init file. For example:

```
(setq resize-mini-windows  t)
```

But if `C-h v` tells you that the value is already `t` or `grow-only` then there must be some other problem. (In that case, recursively bisect your init file to find what is causing it.)

Comment: Weird, even starting Emacs with the -q option to not load any user-specific startup file, the problem remains as shown in the screenshot, where the bottom-down arrow is slightly covered. How should I proceed?

Comment: First, try `emacs -Q` (not `q`), just to be sure. You can then try filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. But this might be a toolkit problem that the Emacs developers cannot fix directly. Anyway, file a bug report if you can reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`, and they will let you know whether they can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the arrows:

```
(set-window-scroll-bars (mini-buffer-window) nil nil) ; Hide tiny scrollbar in minibuffer
```

Also check this variable, which I have set in my config:

```
(setq max-mini-window-height 1) ; Don't let echo area grow
                                ; This is useful for forcing
                                ; 'shell-command-on-region' output to
                                ; be forced to a new buffer, and not
                                ; pasted in the echo area
```

For my comment on `shell-command-on-region`, if `resize-mini-windows` is non-nil (which is currently the default), and the shell command's output is not short enough for the echo area, then it is placed in a new buffer. This is often useful if you're trying to manipulate output of shell commands in emacs.

This minibuffer setting can sometimes mess with reading important messages, like when I was configuring `lsp-mode` for code navigation. It's easy to disable the `max-mini-window-height` variable for a session.